# How to fix the output shape in Keras 2.1.0

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I get a dense layer shape error with Keras Version 2.1.0. This problem only happens with this version of Keras (2.1.0). I am in no position to upgrade the version since it's on a cluster so I am trying to find a fix for the time being. My model is defined as below.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=config["optimizer"],
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I have done one hot encoding as shown below.

```
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, 10)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, 10)
```

The model summary is

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 30, 30, 32)        896       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 28, 28, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 14, 14, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 14, 14, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 12544)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 128)               1605760   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 10)                1290      
=================================================================
Total params: 1,626,442
Trainable params: 1,626,442
Non-trainable params: 0
_____________________________________
```

The error I get is :

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have 2
>   dimensions, but got array with shape (50000, 1, 10)

The exact same code works perfectly in Keras 2.2.4

Comment: @MiguelÁngelRetamozoSanchez  that doesnt work.

Comment: This error is thrown because your target has shape (50000, 1,10) try `y_train = y_train.reshape(-1, 10)` and `y_test = y_test.reshape(-1, 10)`